# Communication with grandchild component

Tags: vue.js, components, communication

I have three components named

A.vue > B.vue (sub component of A) > C.vue (sub component of B)

A receives direct data from core back-end. I want to pass the data to C. I am currently using Props for doing this where A sends the data to B, B sends the data to C.

It works but I am curious to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this communication.

Comment: This is a common question : built-in vuejs event, event bus pattern or vuex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A global event bus is a common way of handling this.

```
// event-bus.js
const bus = new Vue()
export default bus
```

Then you can import `event-bus.js` in your components and communicate through:

```
bus.$emit('event', 'payload')
....
bus.$on('event', payload => { ... })
```

I prefer leveraging a state manager, `vuex`, for this, however. Store/module state's reactivity allows you to observe changes when `commiting` mutations. `mapGetters, mapMutations, and mapActions` are very helpful here.